# Best way to convert Observable<T[]> to Observable<T>

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have a method that returns Observable, within the method there is some logic that unfortunately means I will end up with Observable<T[]> where the array will only have one value which is the one I wish to return. I assume this can be done in the pipe operator but im not sure how, and doing it via subscribe seems hacky

Whats the best way to get the first value of Observable<T[]> and return Observable?

```
getByKey(key: any, options?: EntityActionOptions): Observable<T> {
  let obsArray: Observable<T[]> = someMethod(); //Business Logic that gets Observable<T[]> with one expected value
  let obsReturn: Observable<T> = obsArray.SomePipeLogic // Get the first object in the array and convert to observable

  return obsReturn
}
```

Comment: `obsArray.pipe(map(v => v[0]))`

Comment: `obsArray.pipe(mergeAll())`